# Cannot install gdal or osgeo using .venv - error: legacy-install-failure

Tags: gdal, installation, linux, osgeo, pip

I have cloned a git repo which one of the required package there is to have gdal installed. The computer is Linux and I use vs code to connect reomtly.
at the beginning I naively tried to install gdal with:

```
pip install gdal
```

and then with :

```
pip install osgeo
```

and also :

```
pip install GDAL==3.3.2
```

but all gave me the same error:

> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
> problem with pip. error: legacy-install-failure
>
> × Encountered error while trying to install package. ╰─> GDAL
>
> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

Things I have tried to do :

1. [follow this instructions](https://mothergeo-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/how-to/gdal-ubuntu-pkg.html)  , everything run well beside the part of the actual gdal installing which failed (Same error)
2. install Fiona before - didn't change anything (pip install fiona)
3. install [pygdal](https://pypi.org/project/pygdal/) - got the same error
4. use pip freeze to copy another environment that I have that has gdal working there (I don't remember how I made it work last time) - same error, doesn't install it....
   5.Trying to install  osgeo_utils ...same results...same error

Weird thing is that when I print this on cmd:

```
>>>ogrinfo --version
GDAL 3.3.2, released 2021/09/01
```

which seems like it is already installed, so maybe I can find where is it lcoated?

in the end of the day I would like to be able to import gdal, this way:

```
from osgeo_utils import gdal_pansharpen
```

I know I can try maybe with conda but I am afraid it will create other bugs with the environment as it is cloned.

so, my goal is to be able to import gdal and use it in my notebooks.

Linux distribution and version: Zorin OS 16.1

Created environment:

```
~/git/demo$ python3.10 -m venv .venv
...
~/git/demo$ pip install -r requirments.txt
```

I found out the gdal is installed somewhere on the same OS but I couldn't use pip to install it and use it in python.

Comment: @user2856 I have added the information, let me know if more information should be added.

Comment: Someone has managed to do it with pip lately https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72887400/install-gdal-on-linux-ubuntu-20-04-4lts-for-python.

Comment: Yes, I started writing "Don't install gdal with pip (unless you know what you're doing and are comfortable installing all the build dependencies)" but decided that since it's a pain in the proverbial and you end up with the same version of GDAL anyway (if you use the packaged build deps instead of manually collecting them and building from source which is even more pain) that there's just no point trying to do so.

Comment: @user30184 your answer actually was of value (for me anyway). In the first link [#3060](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/3060) Even Roualt recommends conda :) which is my preferred method of installing GDAL on Windows/Linux.  But your second link [#4352](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/4352) is gold, there's a comment from Cristoph Gohlke noting the new unofficial binary wheels page is [github.com/cgohlke/gdal.whl](https://github.com/cgohlke/gdal.whl) now that [~gohlke/pythonlibs](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs) is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 4):

As you already have GDAL installed, just let your virtual env use it by adding the `--system-site-packages` flag.

```
python -m venv --system-site-packages .venv
```

And just to show it works:

```
.venv/bin/python -c "from osgeo import gdal; print(gdal.__version__)"
3.4.1

.venv/bin/python -c "from osgeo_utils import gdal_pansharpen; print(gdal_pansharpen)"
<module 'osgeo_utils.gdal_pansharpen' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo_utils/gdal_pansharpen.py'>
```

And if you don't have GDAL already installed:

```
sudo apt install gdal-bin python3-gdal
```

Comment: I have ran "python -m venv --system-site-packages .venv" and then I have tried to import gdal using "from osgeo import gdal" and also "from osgeo_utils import gdal_pansharpen" but I get error : "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'"

Comment: Did you delete the `.venv` directory before re-running `python -m venv  etc...`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, to resolve it, you just have to complete these following steps:

```
pip install pipwin
```

Wait while installing, then after :

```
pip install gdal
```

PS: Those steps are for windows users

Comment: This is a linux specific question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while installing ogr2osm (https://github.com/roelderickx/ogr2osm).

I solved it by using the OSGeo4W shell (which already had GDAL pre-installed) and installing ogr2osm via this shell.